# What is the purpose of <modulename>.mod.c file generated while compiling a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

What is the purpose of `modulename`.mod.c file generated while compiling a kernel module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

.mod.c is a file that basically contains the information about the module which are required at the time of inserting, like version number and symbols which are not defined locally. If symbols are not defined in existing running kernel or version is not matched with the running kernel, the module insertion will fail.

Comment: Looking into content, `.mod.c` file is C file, contained definition of `__this_module` variable (of type `struct module`) and  `__module_depends` (of type `const char[]`). There is no symbols information in this file, and it is definitely used only on *compile* stage. When the module is inserted into kernel, only information in `.ko` file is checked.